# How to write multiple if else null statement in XML template

Tags: xml, thymeleaf

I have an XML template where if a variable is true, this element is created:

```
<Tracking th:Val="Y"/>
```

If it is false this is created:

```
<Tracking th:Val="N"/>
```

If it is null, no element is created.

Currently I have this:

```
<th:block th:if="${tracking}">
    <Tracking th:Val="Y"/>
 </th:block>
 <th:block th:if="${!tracking}">
    <Tracking th:Val="N"/>
 </th:block>
```

Is there a better way to write this? I'm thinking maybe this:

```
<th:block th:if="${tracking != null}" >
    <Tracking th:Val="${tracking} ? 'Y' : 'N'"/>
</th:block>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would represent it like this:

```
<Tracking th:if="${tracking != null}" th:Val="${tracking ? 'Y' : 'N'}"/>
```

(There is no need for the extra `th:block`.)